# Does it sound natural to native speakers: „sich in den Mittelpunkt stellen“

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase, idiom

To express

> the figure becomes the focus of today's newspapers

can I render it as the following:

> die Persönlichkeit stellt sich heute in den Mittelpunkt der Presse

Does it sound natural to native speakers?

Comment: This makes it sound as if someone unilaterally decides to becomes today's "leading story" and succeeds, when in real life all you can do is to put out good P.R. and *hope* that it works.

Comment: @KilianFoth Thanks for your comment! How about this : die Zeitungen stellen heute die Persönlichkeit in den Fokus der Bericherstattung. Does this sentence make good sense to native speakers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be understood with a slightly changed word order, but is horrible imagery:

> Die Persönlichkeit stand heute im Mittelpunkt der Presse

Apart from *newspapers*, "Presse", as in English, still literally means *press* (squeezing device) - You don't really want to place yourself in the center of it. Also note that "Mittelpunkt" is the *center* - Where's the center of *newspapers*?

A closer translation would be

> Die Persönlichkeit stand heute im Fokus der Berichterstattung.

Also, note your verb usage: The English original uses *becomes*, wich is kind of a passive action - Your translation used "stellte sich", which indicates an action on the side of the person and thus implies the person actively moved himself into focus.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  How about this : die Zeitungen stellen heute die Persönlichkeit in den Fokus der Bericherstattung. Does this sentence make good sense to native speakers?